# Mui move asterisk before label

Tags: material-ui

How can I move `*` to the start of label?
`*Outlined` instead of `Outlined*`

```js
<TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" required/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style it with css, or styled, or sx prop, or makeStyles, or theme style overrides.

Just add style to the label component:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

This is for global use:

```
.MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-required {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

If you want it to be valid only for outlined inputs then replace `MuiInputLabel-root` with `MuiInputLabel-outlined` (or add next to it)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.MuiFormLabel-asterisk {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

After doing above css, you would have to tweak translate values for label a bit. Adding 1-2 px more to x value

```css
.MuiInputLabel-outlined {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate(22px, 20px) scale(1);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```